# Ajax.BeginFrom validate against model

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model

I am new to ASP.Net MVC..

Here is the problem...

I have an View which list all the FilterTypes. In the same View..I need to have a search option which is based on AJAX.  I got the ajax part working. But How can I make the Ajax post validate against the UserEnity model ?. Is it posisble to move the Ajax part of the view to a partialView ?.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is sample

```
@model IEnumerable<UserEntity>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "FiltrationType", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "post",
        UpdateTargetId = "gridContent",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <p> <b>Search Filter Type </b> @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
        <input type="submit" name="cmdFiltrationSearch" value="Search" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="cmdFiltrationClear" value="Clear" onclick="ClearFiltrationTypeSearchText()" /> 
        </p>     
    }

<div id="gridContent">

   @if (ViewBag.DataRetriveStatus != null )
   {
     <span class ="ErrorDiv"> @ViewBag.DataRetriveStatus </span><br />
   }
   else
   {
   @Html.Partial("_filtrationGrid", Model)
   }
</div>
```

Good news is I can not post the model data after chainging the form names to match to model entity names liek following..

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "User", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    UpdateTargetId = "gridContent",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table class ="UserSearch">
        <tr> 
            <th> Account </th>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("DisplayName")
             </td>
        </tr>
          <tr> 
            <th> First Name</th>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("FirstName")  </td>
        </tr>
          <tr> 
            <th> Last Name </th>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("LastName")  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>   
    <input type="submit" name="cmdUserSearch" value="Search" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="cmdUserClear" value="Clear" onclick="ClearUserSearchText()" /> 
    </p>     
}
```

But the jquery validation does not work on the form ..any idea why ?. But validating in controller as `ModelState.IsValid` works fine.

Here is my entity model

```
public class UserSearch
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display Name is Required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Display Name length should be between 2 and 30 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Display Name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "First Name length should be between 2 and 30 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Last Name length should be between 2 and 30 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and contorller code...

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(string cmdUserSearch, string cmdUserClear,  UserSearch entity)
{

   if (ModelState.IsValid) 
   {
     // some code
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post your controller code?  It looks like the only thing you are submitting here is a string variable `SearchString`, what kind of model are you trying to bind against?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to bind against UserEntity model. Here is my sample controller  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(string cmdFiltrationSearch, string cmdFiltrationClear, string SearchString, UserEntity entity)
        {  }When I debug..the entity value is null.

Comment: Can you also post your entity model?

Comment: I just updated my post with more information. Thanks for checking in and I look forward for help.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check - I've tried this in a sample project - worked well using MVC 4 which I presume you are using.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I can just guess, but most common solution is to check if the [jquery.validate.unobtrusive-ajax](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js) script is included.

**UPDATE**

Another possible reason below:

Most likely the issue appears because your model is `IEnumerable<UserEntity>`. Therefore the `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<UserEntity>>` (which is the type of the `Html` property you are using to render the helpers) has no information about the `UserEntity` validation rules and renders simple inputs with type equal to `text` with not attributes required for client validation.

This explains why the server-side validation works - you are expecting to get the `UserSearch` instance as parameter of the action method, so now the validation rules are applied.

One of the possible solutions would be to extend the model with the properties you want to validate on client using built-in validation. For example you can use the following model.

```
public class UserSearchResults : UserSearch
{
    public IEnumerable<UserEntity> Items { get; set; }
}
```

`@model` has to be changed to our new `UserSearchResults` class.
You'll have to update your controller to pass the `UserSearchResults` into the view.
And add the following changes to the razor.

```
 <table class ="UserSearch">
    <tr> 
        <th> Account </th>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DisplayName)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th> First Name </th>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <th> Last Name </th>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and update the usage of partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("_filtrationGrid", Model.Items)
```

Using the code above will tell the `HtmlHelper` with which model it is dealing and the validation should be applied.

In your case there might be a better way of composing models but the main point is that when the view is rendered, the engine has no idea that the value of those inputs will be posted to an action method that is expecting to get `UserSearch` class instance, therefore they are treated as ordinary inputs with no validation attached.

---

This is not related to the question, but I wonder why do you have these parameters in your action method `string cmdUserSearch, string cmdUserClear`. Based on the code that is in your question those will be equal to `null` all the time.

As well it would be better to change the type of the input with name `cmdFiltrationClear` to `button` instead of `submit`, otherwise there it is possible that it will still submit the form.

Comment: cmdUserSearch, cmdUserClear  are used to check at the controller which button the user cicked. If Search is clicked..then data is pulled from the database and populated. If cler is clicked then using Jquery I will make all the textbox empty and in controller i populate all the data from the table.

Comment: Also as of making a UserSearchResults. My UserSearh is a subset of properties found in UserEntity. I created UserSearch class with properties I needed in the User Search form.

In UserSearch class EMail is not decorated with [Required] attribute while in UserEntity email is decorated with [Required] attribute.
In the form if I put email as 
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
then on clicking submit..form displays "Email is required".

Answer (score 0):

Does your web.config file have these values set and to true?

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

As for including the ajax part as partial view, you most certainly can do that.

Comment: Yes I have this in web.config. Jquery validation works fine in other views.